# Join two tables with different column counts

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to create a table fom two different tables

```
Table 1 has 

ID   Place      Value   Date  
--------------------------------
1    Place     Value1   Date1
2    Place1    Value2   Date2
4    Place2    Value1   Date1
7    Place3    Value2   Date1

and Table2 has 

ID    Name        Values
------------------------
3    ColName1    Value2
5    ColName2    Value1
6    ColName3    Value2
```

Now I want to create a new table with ID, Table1.Place, Table1.Date and Table2.Value

I tried using

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblNewTable] 
SELECT tbl1.ID, tbl1.Place, tbl1.Date
FROM [Tabble1] tbl1 
UNION
SELECT tbl2.Value 
FROM [Table2] tbl2
```

but it says that All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Please Note that ID is unique in both the tables.

Comment: What is common in both the tables? do they have any?

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: Added NULLs for missing columns

Comment: What @AllanS.Hansen said - if you add in two null values to your second select list, I,e, SELECT tbl2.value, null, null FROM [Table2] tbl2, then the union will work. If you want a specific value, put that in instead. That said, the result will likely be gibberish. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're asking for.  If you want to use a `UNION` statement, the same number of columns have to be in each query (with the same data types).  So in your case, if you're desired results are to get a list of ids 1 to 7, then you'd need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblNewTable] 
SELECT tbl1.ID, tbl1.Place, tbl1.Date, tbl1.Value
FROM [Tabble1] tbl1 
UNION
SELECT tbl2.ID, NULL, NULL, tbl2.Value 
FROM [Table2] tbl2
```

This will result in:

```
ID   Place     Value    Date  
--------------------------------
1    Place     Value1   Date1
2    Place1    Value2   Date2
3    NULL      Value2   NULL
4    Place2    Value1   Date1
5    NULL      Value1   NULL
6    NULL      Value2   NULL
7    Place3    Value2   Date1
```

Alternatively, you are looking to `JOIN` your tables to get a common result set:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblNewTable] 
SELECT tbl1.ID, tbl1.Place, tbl1.Date, tbl2.Value
FROM [Tabble1] tbl1  
    JOIN [Table2] tbl2 ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID
```

In your supplied data, this will result in no records though.

Answer (score 1):

Union should be on two tables both which have same number and type of columns.
The query should be as follows. What you need is a join as follows:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblNewTable] 
SELECT tbl1.ID, tbl1.Place, tbl1.Date, tbl2.Value 
FROM [Tabble1] tbl1,  [Table2] tbl2
WHERE tbl1.value = tbl2.value
```

Comment: You should specifically indicate your join with the `JOIN` keyword, and *not* with the ANSI-89 syntax.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 I can't infer that from written SQL query. Which environment do this query belong?

Comment: "Yes" you can, and "yes" you are.  You have `Tabble1` listed first in your `FROM`, clearly indicating that you deducted `Tabble1` belongs on the "LEFT."  And all I'm saying is that we really shouldn't be specifying our JOINs with a syntax that was deprecated 25 years ago.